# c# checkbox is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkboxlist

I am new to this c# coding.
I am trying to write a code using checkboxes. Below is code in design flow

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="lblOwn" runat="server" Text="Owned by You :"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chbxOwn" runat="server"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="onAckTypeChanged3" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem>2 wheeler</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>4 wheeler</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="2 w"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="4 w"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And following is codebehind

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hid1();
        Hid2();
    }
    protected void onAckTypeChanged3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chbxOwn.SelectedItem.Text == "2 wheeler")
        {
            Vis1();
        }
        if (chbxOwn.SelectedItem.Text == "4 wheeler")
        {
           Vis2();
        }
    }
    private void Hid1()
    {
        Label1.Visible = false;
    }
    private void Hid2()
    {
        Label2.Visible = false;
    }
    private void  Vis1()
    {
        Label1.Visible = true;
    }
    private void Vis2()
    {
        Label2.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

When "2 wheeler" checkbox is checked "2 w" label is visible. But when i check "4 wheeler" it doesnot shows both the labels. i want to know where i am making a mistake. Also when i de-select both the checkboxes there is an Null reference exception generated.

can you please help me out with these problems
1. Checking both the checkbox should display both the labels.
2. De-selecting should not produce null reference exception.

Thanks in advance
Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: can you test it some more times, check them in different orders etc?

Comment: When you check "4 wheeler", are both checkboxes then checked?

Comment: @SamIam : i did checked them in different orders. first checking 2 wheeler -> shows 2 w label. then checking 4 wheeler -> hides 2 w and shows 4 w. at this point both checkbox are selected. when i de-select 4 wheeler -> shows 2 w label. after de-selecting both shows null reference exception

Comment: @JonathanWood : please refer my previous comment. you may find your answer. Please let me know if i need to clear something more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
protected void onAckTypeChanged3(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in chbxOwn.Items)
    {
        if (item.Text == "2 wheeler" && item.Selected)
        {
            Vis1();
        }
        if (item.Text == "4 wheeler" && item.Selected)
        {
            Vis2();
        }
    }
}
```

It works like a charm..!!

Here is the working demo: **[DEMO](http://vishalsuthar.studio2.coderun.com/ASPNETWebSite/)**

Answer (score 1):

Look at [ListControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.items.aspx) for an example on how to use the `Items` property to determine the selected items in a CheckBoxList. The `SelectedItem` property returns the item with the lowest index. When no items are selected, `SelectedItem` returns null which is why you would get a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the **onAckTypeChanged3** event as follow

```
protected void onAckTypeChanged3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (ListItem checkBoxItem in chbxOwn.Items)
            {
                if (checkBoxItem.Selected == true)
                {
                    if (checkBoxItem.Text == "2 wheeler")
                    {
                        Vis1();
                    }
                    if (checkBoxItem.Text == "4 wheeler")
                    {
                        Vis2();
                    }
                }                
            }            
        }
```